# Sill Protector Illuminated verify lights off

Tags: electrical, wiring, sensor

I just got Illuminated Sill Protector Installed in My Car - Mahindra XUV 3OO. I cannot verify with certainty but I feel that the Sill Protector lights remain ON even when the door is closed.
Is this kind of wiring wrong?
How can I verify this with certainty?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Somewhere on the door frame is a little button-looking thing that is the switch that indicates the door is closed. Often along the the hinge side of the door opening, sometimes on the opposite side. Push the button in, see if the lights go off.

Comment: I checked the switch - it has no effect. The mechanic said it is connected to the Rooftop lights.

Comment: @Raunak - OK, what do the rooftop (I presume you mean the light in the cabin?) lights do when you push the switch to indicate the door is closed? If they go out, well, your sill lights should as well. Or pull the fuse for the 'rooftop' lights and see if that does the trick.